# Translating the months in the archive view

Tags: views, 6, i18n-l10n

I need the months in views' default archive view to display in a different language, just changing the language in Drupal doesn't seem to be helping, string overrides in settings.php aren't doing the trick either. I also tried downloading and importing the views language file but that too has failed. Where can I make this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have tried all those options, what if you try to replace the respective values from a common view template, using for example, [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) PHP functions, to change this values?

for example: Here is the part of views-view-unformatted.tpl.php when each result is printed:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>">   
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

you can use a custom `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` specific to your view, and use `preg_replace()` to detect and replace any specific term in $row, according terms that you want. for example

```
<?php
$string = $row;
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/jan/';
$patterns[1] = '/feb/';
$patterns[2] = '/mar/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'othermar';
$replacements[1] = 'otherfeb';
$replacements[0] = 'otherjan';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

see preg_replace() to get more details. I guess that you can use Devel module to see impact of this way against your site performance.

I hope information be useful.